# What is the difference between CreateModuleCatalog() and ConfigureModuleCatalog() in PRISM?

Tags: c#, wpf, module, prism, catalog

Basically...

```
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
    {
        var catalog = base.CreateModuleCatalog();

        var moduleInfo = new ModuleInfo("HelloWorldModule", "Testing.HelloWorldModule"));
        catalog.AddModule(moduleInfo);

        return catalog;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(Testing.HelloWorldModule));
    }
```

They both seem to be doing the same thing here, so what's the real difference? I guess I'm asking what you're *supposed to* do differently from within them (because obviously I can move the code around).

Answer (score 0):

PRISMs `run` method first calls `CreateModuleCatalog` and assigns its return value to `BootStrapper.ModuleCatalog`. So really you must create the ModuleCatalog there. For configuring you could use either method, the only difference would be, where in the log a potential exception would be shown. The relevant code in `MefBootstrapper.Run` for example is this:

```
        this.Logger.Log(Resources.CreatingModuleCatalog, Category.Debug, Priority.Low);
        this.ModuleCatalog = this.CreateModuleCatalog();
        if (this.ModuleCatalog == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.NullModuleCatalogException);
        }

        this.Logger.Log(Resources.ConfiguringModuleCatalog, Category.Debug, Priority.Low);
        this.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
```